# pdo update statement using concat is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am still new to PDO and am having trouble getting the update statement below to work.  I want to be able to update the name field by just appending to the current value with a comma and the new name.  Resulting name field should be like james,doug,paul,etc.  This is probably a simple answer but I haven't been able to find a solution through a lot of googling!

Thanks in advance

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET name = concat(name, ',' :name) WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute( array('name' => $name, 'id' => $id) );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you lack comma inside your concat.

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET name = concat(name, ',', :name) WHERE id = :id");
                      ^                                        ^ here                 ^
```

Comment: uggh! thank you.  I think it was the quotes somehow too.  I knew this had to be simple.  Thanks