# PDO appending input value to existing value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having issues appending new posted data to existing data.

Right now when the submit button is clicked it overwrites the existing value for 'notes' with only $header and the new $_POST["notes"] value.

What I would like it to do is be:
$header + $_POST["notes"] + $notes (existing data)

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    // Database connection file
    include_once("../config.php");

    // Get id from url
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // Selecting data associated with this id
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id=:id";
    $query = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $notes = $row['notes'];
    }
?>

<?php
        // Create Header
        $header = "----- Updated on " . date("Y-m-d") . " at " . date("h:i:sa") . " ----- <br>";
        // Current note data
        $currentnotes = $notes;
        // Append Header + Post + Current Data
        $appendednotes = $header;
        $appendednotes .= $_POST["notes"];
        $appendednotes .= "<br>";
        $appendednotes .= $currentnotes;

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $notes=$appendednotes;

        // Update the table
        $sql = "UPDATE testtable SET
            notes=:notes
        WHERE id=:id";

        $query = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
    
        $query->bindparam(':id', $id);
        $query->bindparam(':notes', $notes);

        $query->execute();

        // Redirect to the display page
        header("Location: index.php");
        
    }
?>
```

This is the closest example to finding what I want to do, but I am unsure how to adapt it:
[php post to variable and then append to txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272192/php-post-to-variable-and-then-append-to-txt)

Comment: Try with `CONCAT` ... [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153329/7644018)

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of $notes to see if a values is retrieved?

Comment: Thank you very much! Follow up question: now the data is posted oldest to newest, how would I go newest to oldest?

Comment: Change the order of the CONCAT parameters, if this is what you mean?

Comment: Exactly! Just switched them and it worked (didn't know if it had to be in a certain order or not). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Paul, I updated my code to this and it works!

```
// Update the table
$sql = "UPDATE survey SET
    notes=concat(:notes, notes)
WHERE id=:id";
```

Comment: ...as with most function arguments/parameters (especially with CONCAT), order does matter, and you got it! :-)

Comment: Don't forget that [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) returns `NULL` whenever any of its arguments is `NULL`.